# How to ask if someone is doing the same thing as before without using "still" for negative connotations?

Tags: meaning, questions, politeness, indirect-speech, continuous-aspect

> "So, X, are you still living in Y?"

> "So, A, are you still working at B?"

For a conversation opener or continuer, is there an alternative way to enquire, interest, about someone elses situation without using the word "still"?

I should say I'm not a fan of "still" used in this way as a conversation opener and prefer to find another way to open or continue a converation.

I'm not a fan because I feel in this context, "still" seems to me put down the other person, especially if they reply yes. I certainly don't like to be asked a question like this. It has the implication of suggesting that the receiver is an underachiever or lacking of ambition.

For the wonderful diverse language that English is, with many ways to say something, this enquiring question demonstrates the potential negative sense of the word still.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for a way to ask an [open ended question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-ended_question)?

Comment: I think tone of voice makes a huge difference. Are you still working at **B**? with a level tone all the way through but a rising tone at the end, indicates interest. However, "Are you STILL working at B" with the rise on "still" indicates derision.  If only we had an accurate way of indicating voice tone in print.

Comment: Perhaps you could avoid the issue altogether by saying some thing like, "So, Z, where are you living/working these days?"

Comment: You can keenly ask "How is life in X these days?" And you should be able to tell a lot from their tone and body language how to take it on.

Comment: How are things going at x? Are you enjoying your work? How’s the old neighborhood?

Comment: The only way it can be considered negative is because of the connotation placed on it, perhaps by yourself, outside of the word *still*. *Are you **still** a millionaire?* *Are you **still** happy and enjoying life?*

Comment: I would ask if they *continue* to live at X or perhaps have they *continued* to work at Y.  @Jason "You're not *still* a millionaire are you? You poor thing.

Comment: @Elliot That only sounds bad because you've put particular emphasis on it. It has nothing to do with the word itself. You can emphasize anything you want and make it sound good or bad. "You've lost your leg in an accident? Oh, how delightful! You are quite fortunate to have had such an experience. It sounds fascinating."

Comment: Would it be too simple to remove the word *still* and just ask your question? Or even *Living at X?* or *Working at Y?*

Comment: @Jason; Forgive me. I only mean to get your heart racing and your fingers dancing. If that is the only activity of your day I consider my task well served.

Comment: There is nothing inherently negative about "still".  (Unless you're a revenuer, that is.)

Comment: +1 @RichardKayser, Weather Vane.